# Javascript prevent multiple search words

Tags: javascript, html

Strange behavior. When I add this script on my page, I'm no longer able to put a space into the search field.

```
<script>
    $('#demo1_thumbs').desoSlide({
        main: {
            container: '#demo1_main_image',
            cssClass: 'img-responsive'
        },
        effect: 'sideFade',
        caption: true
    });
</script>
```

I put a demo page here to see the behavior:
https://www.testvrij.be/index2.php

When I remove the script, the slide doesn't work anymore. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is `desoSlide()`?

Comment: `desoSlide()` uses space to trigger the slider.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of desoSlide? The documentation says that the default is `controls: {keys: false}` but your version defaults it to true.

Comment: That change was in version 2.0.0, you're running 1.2.3.1, which is 8 years old.

Comment: I didn't know desoSlide was using space to trigger. Thanks. That must be the reason. Is this with version 2.0 still the case? If so, no point in upgrading I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old version of `desoSLide` you're using, keyboard control of the slideshow is enabled by default.

You can either upgrade to the current version, or you can override the default:

```
$('#demo1_thumbs').desoSlide({
    main: {
        container: '#demo1_main_image',
        cssClass: 'img-responsive'
    },
    effect: 'sideFade',
    caption: true,
    controls: {
        keys: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect fix. Thanks!